# How to show broadcast (simultaneous sending of two messages) in sequence diagrams in PlantUml

Tags: sequence-diagram, plantuml

I have this bit of plantuml:

```
@startuml

title Sequence diagram

A -> B : First
B -> C : Second
B -> A : Third

@enduml
```

It renders like this:

[image: Sequence diagram with unaligned sequence arrows]

I would like to get this instead, with two arrows "happening concurrently":

[image: Sequence diagram with aligned arrows]

Any hints on how to achieve this are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find an answer with the Teoz pragma https://plantuml.com/teoz

```
@startuml
!pragma teoz true
title Sequence diagram

A -> B : First
B -> C : Second
&B -> A : Third

@enduml
```

[image: Broadcast]